# with_pg_search_highlight with associated field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

Currently I am using trying to perform pg_search with with_pg_search_highlight on an associated table field and I am getting:

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "pg_search_17ebb3b05265b756196ca6"`

I am using rubygem
pg_search -v 2.3.2

on my item model 
**item.rb**

```
belongs_to :brand

include PgSearch::Model
pg_search_scope :associated_search,
  against: [[:name, 'A']],
  associated_against: {brand: [:code]},
  using: {
    tsearch: {
      prefix: true,
      dictionary: "english",
      negation: true,
      highlight: {
        StartSel: '<b>',
        StopSel: '</b>',
        MaxWords: 10,
        MinWords: 2,
        ShortWord: 4,
        HighlightAll: false,
        MaxFragments: 3,
        FragmentDelimiter: '<br>---<br>'
      }
    }
  }
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
Item.associated_search(params[:query]).with_pg_search_highlight
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Dug a little bit through the issues in the gem and it's actually a 2 year old bug which hasn't been addressed yet.

https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/issues/350